# I deleted npm but its still there

Tags: npm

I want to delete npm from my system and start with a clean slate. So I run `sudo apt remove npm`.

Now, I called `npm -v` and it returned **6.13.7**.

What dose that mean? is it possible that I have two or more installations of npm on my system? which one is considered "global"?

If I run `whereis npm` I get */usr/local/bin/npm* and ls over there tells me its a soft link that points to */usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm*

Should I simply `rm *` the folder and the link?

Answer (score 0):

OK, took my risk and rm'ed the library and link. I did the trick. Now calling `whereis npm` returns an empty list and `npm -v` returns an error message.

So it probably was a path problem caused by improper installation process for node and npm in the first place.